# How to reduce AUGraph implemention size?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I have recently implemented an AUGraph with the a AUSampler node, a AUMixer node and a reverb node. Everything is working just fine. But when I profile the app, the size of the core audio implementation is 19.53 MB. So I downloaded the sample from apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011214

I Profiled this demo and the size taken by the audio graph is exactly 19.53 MB here also.The graph they use don't have as many nodes as my graph does and still it uses the exact same amount of memory.

So it is obvious that the size of the graph is independent of the number of nodes init.

If anyone knows of any ways to optimise this memory usage please help :).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: hmm - is that your loaded sample set?

Comment: @justin  well in both the apple demo and my app,the samples are different.we still get the same size when we profile both the apps.So i don't think its the sample set.Is it the sample rate of the output node that you are talking about?? It is set to 44100.0 Hertz.If that info helps.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i was referring to the sample data (e.g. audio files). if you are loading the same samples/patch/instrument, then those audio files' sample data could be loaded into memory, in part or whole. in the case of the sample you linked, it would be the trombone samples in the demo (8.3 MB) -- the size difference could be that the sample data may be 16 bit in the file and 32 bit in memory, or it could just be because it has loaded and/or cached some things. the allocations instrument should give you detailed backtraces for these allocations -- dig down into them further :)

Comment: ok - specifically, it appears to be the AU sampler's audio streamer buffers. 20 MB

Comment: i don't see any parameters which would affect the allocation sizes for these buffers.

Comment: @justin Thank you for your speedy response :).I will update this thread if i find someway around it.